# Blender 2.79 problems with zooming

Tags: 3d-view, camera

key "." works, shift + ctrl works.
but when zooming with ctrl only or shift only - it stops

for example on a screenshot while zooming out that brown cylinder - it shows black squares like your render is not finished yet

Camera settings?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Probably the inner and the outter faces of your model are too close to each other. Hit N and turn on Backface culling.

Comment: thanks. no, it always worked well. i increased clipping and it almost works well. anyway it stops zooming in or out sometimes and i press .del then